# Requesting a quersystring with a method in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to request a querystring. It's simple to make it work within the `aspx` file, but when I make a method within `a class` and are going to use it, I can't use `Request.QueryString["id"];` because it doesn't show up.

Comment: The `Request` object is an instance like anything else. You need a reference to it if you want to access it's members. Got any code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString
```

Comment: Thank you, you are a lifesaver! <3

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code:

```
var uri = new Uri(Request.QueryString);
```

and then:

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("personId")
```

Comment: The query string should already be a NameValueCollection and doesn't differ much from what OP already has